# Read OPF files with JS

Tags: javascript, epub

I want to open an OPF file using Javascript. I want to create an Epub reade in JS but first I need to reed that file. It's an XML file with .opf extension. I need to read the tags inside that file, but I don't know how to do that.
EDIT:
I found something. Everyone that uses FileReader get the "file" object from an input file, but I want to read a local file in my server. How can I get that file?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAstext(file)
```

Comment: see how to use FileReader in javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679325/epub-and-javascript

Comment: https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/

Comment: I already tried to use epub.js but it's not fine for me. @YogeshJagdale , I edited the question, can you answer me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed method. Now I use PHP xmldomelement.